# How to install sqlsrv php driver on zend server?

Tags: php, sql-server, php-extension, zend-server

I downloaded *"Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server (V 2.0.1)"* from [Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=80e44913-24b4-4113-8807-caae6cf2ca05) and move it to **php_sqlsrv_5.3_nts_vc6.dll** to *"C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\"* next to *"php5.dll"*.

then go to Zend server Panel "Server Setup > Extensions" to turn it on. after restarting php, Zend Server says: "The system could not load this extension"!

What should I do?

**P.S**: Zend Configured on Apache

**edit**: I also tried "php_sqlsrv_5.3_ntc_vc9.dll" but it failed either!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed something in php_error.log:

```
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC6
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
```

Build IDs are the same but VC version are different.
because I put both VC6 and VC9 together in *"phpext"* folder. Zend could not load the correct extension. while I removed VC6 dll, in Zend Panel the error message was still there, even by restarting the php.

I stopped server, remove VC9, start server again, put VC9 in *"phpext"* folder, turn it on from Zend Panel, and restart php.

everything is now ok!

Special Thanks to Kevin :)